# Google Maps: Auto close open InfoWindows?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[On my site](http://www.uptownelite.com/test.html?city=dallas,tx), I'm using Google Maps API v3 to place house markers on the map.

The InfoWindows stay open unless you explicitly click the close icon. Meaning, you can have 2+ InfoWindows open at a time if you hover over the map marker.

**Question**: How do I make it so that only the current active InfoWindow is open and all other InfoWindows are closed? Meaning, no more than 1 InfoWindow will be open at a time?

Comment: As for me it's better to create just _one_ infowindow and update it (it's content and etc), open and close and eveything. But I am pretty sure this approach isn't always applicable.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

There is a [close()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#InfoWindow) function for InfoWindows.  Just keep track of the last opened window, and call the close function on it when a new window is created.

Comment: Upvoted for the suggestion of keeping track of the last opened window only. Looks like a no-brainer, but people forget those things...

Comment: I've just used the exact same technique. Thanks Chris. It was necessary for me, because I am using an array of InfoWindow objects instead of just one that cycles through and grabs the pertinent info. Each InfoWindow has its own separately updating information, so I found this technique quite useful.

Answer (score 71):

alternative solution for this with using many infowindows:
save prev opened infowindow in a variable and then close it when new window opened

```
var prev_infowindow =false; 
...
base.attachInfo = function(marker, i){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'yourmarkerinfocontent'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        if( prev_infowindow ) {
           prev_infowindow.close();
        }

        prev_infowindow = infowindow;
        infowindow.open(base.map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Like this one. Simple to understand and implement

Comment: Forgive my naivety, but WTF is base?

Comment: I don't understand why it's not the default behavior in Google maps V3 ...

Comment: Best and simplest solution I've found so far. thank you!

Answer (score 27):

```
//assuming you have a map called 'map'
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng1, map:map});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click',
    function(){
        infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent('Marker #1');//update the content for this marker
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);//"move" the info window to the clicked marker and open it
    }
);
var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(10,10);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng2, map:map});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click',
    function(){
        infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent('Marker #2');//update the content for this marker
        infowindow.open(map, marker2);//"move" the info window to the clicked marker and open it
    }
);
```

This will "move" the info window around to each clicked marker, in effect closing itself, then reopening (and panning to fit the viewport) in its new location. It changes its contents before opening to give the desired effect. Works for n markers.

Comment: Quick note: repeated calls to infowindow.open() are sufficient; the window doesn't need to be closed first.

Comment: @Eric, while you're technically correct, I've noticed a bug that sometimes causes info windows to show up in their last position. Forcing closed first defeats said bug.

Answer (score 26):

Create infowindow and just change its content without needing to keep track of an open one, etc.

```
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
...
function createMarker(...) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     ...,
     descrip: infowindowHtmlContent  
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setOptions({
        content: this.descrip,
        maxWidth:300
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: That's really elegant - only using a single infowindow and changing the content avoids having to keep track of / close the previous one.

Comment: This solution is very elegant indeed and works like a charm. +1

Answer (score 12):

> Declare a variable for active window

```
var activeInfoWindow;
```

> and bind this code in marker listener

```
 marker.addListener('click', function () {
    if (activeInfoWindow) { activeInfoWindow.close();}
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    activeInfoWindow = infowindow;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It really works for when clicking anywhere on the  map.

Comment: Cheers dude, out of all the suggestions, this worked the best for me and is clean AF.

Comment: best answer here for GMaps (@angular/google-maps": "^13.2.3) using the native API and with multiple markers, built using the official guides.

Answer (score 9):

From this link http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/09/google-maps-api-3-infowindows/:

> Teo: The easiest way to do this is to
>   just have one instance of the
>   InfoWindow object that you reuse over
>   and over again. That way when you
>   click a new marker the infoWindow is
>   “moved” from where it’s currently at,
>   to point at the new marker.
>
> Use its setContent method to load it
>   with the correct content.

Comment: I don't believe this applies since I'm using Google Maps v3 API

Comment: Plus, the article you linked too does not demo more than 1 marker

Comment: I've used a single infowindow in the same fashion for several sites.  Click one, the open one closes automatically.

Comment: How do you associate multiple marks with a single InfoWindow?

Answer (score 4):

There is a easier way besides using the close() function. if you create a variable with the InfoWindow property it closes automatically when you open another.

```
var info_window;
var map;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(33.84659, -84.35686);

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: chicago,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'loading'
    )};

createLocationOnMap('Location Name 1', new google.maps.LatLng(33.84659, -84.35686), '<p><strong>Location Name 1</strong><br/>Address 1</p>');
createLocationOnMap('Location Name 2', new google.maps.LatLng(33.84625, -84.36212), '<p><strong>Location Name 1</strong><br/>Address 2</p>');

}

function createLocationOnMap(titulo, posicao, conteudo) {            
    var m = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: titulo,
        position: posicao,
        html: conteudo
    });            

    google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function () {                
        info_window.setContent(this.html);
        info_window.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var map;
var infowindow;
...
function createMarker(...) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        ...
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 300
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
...
function initialize() {
    ...
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        };
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I needed to close the infowindow when not clicked a marker so just on the map

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
google.maps.event.addListener(yourMarker, 'mouseover', function () {
        yourInfoWindow.open(yourMap, yourMarker);

    });

google.maps.event.addListener(yourMarker, 'mouseout', function () {
        yourInfoWindow.open(yourMap, yourMarker);

    });
```

Then you can just hover over it and it will close itself.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround but it doesn't answer the question and wouldn't work on touch only devices.

Answer (score 1):

I stored a variable at the top to keep track of which info window is currently open, see below.

```
var currentInfoWin = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[counter], 'click', function() {      
    if (currentInfoWin !== null) {
        currentInfoWin.close(map, this); 
    }
    this.infoWin.open(map, this); 
    currentInfoWin = this.infoWin;  
});
```

Comment: What is [counter] doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used if you are using many markers in a for loop (Django here). You can set an index on each marker and set that index every time you open a window. Closing the previously saved index:

```
markers = Array();
infoWindows = Array();
var prev_infowindow =false;
{% for obj in objects %}
var contentString = 'your content'
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
          });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: {lat: {{ obj.lat }}, lng: {{ obj.lon }}},
               map: map,
               title: '{{ obj.name }}',
               infoWindowIndex : {{ forloop.counter0 }}
          });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
            function(event)
            {
           if( prev_infowindow ) {
               infoWindows[prev_infowindow].close();
                }
                prev_infowindow = this.infoWindowIndex;
                infoWindows[this.infoWindowIndex].open(map, this);
            }
        );

        infoWindows.push(infowindow);
        markers.push(marker);

      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var contentString = "Location: " + results[1].formatted_address;    
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(){ 
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}));
```