# Close all currently open infowindows in Google Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps v3, how do I close all currently open infowindows?

I can't just keep track of the last opened infowindow in a variable, [as some have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223574/google-maps-auto-close-open-infowindows), because in my setup each marker has unique text, and so I have to bind the infowindow to the marker at the point where it is created.

```
_.each(new_companies, function(c) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.com_d_coo_y_wgs84,
      c.com_d_coo_x_wgs84);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
  marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: getTooltipText(c)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      marker.info.open(map, marker);
      // How to close all currently open info windows?
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.info.open(map, marker);
  });
  newco_markers.push(marker);
});
```

I guess I could loop through all the markers in `newco_markers` and close the infowindow for each, but that feels inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using one infowindow and updating it's content and position via [API methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow): setPosition() and setContent()

Edit:

I made an assumption that you only needed one infowindow at a time. If you need more than one then you could try keeping a map(object) or array with references to the open info windows.

Comment: This is the best solution - the only reason you should need more than one infowindow object is if you have to have multiple infowindows open at the same time

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's going to work, because if I try to set the content with `infowindow.setContent(getTooltipText(c))` inside the loop, I end up with the same text bound to each marker.

Comment: Ah, figured it out - set the content as a property of `marker`, then `infowindow.setContent(marker.content)`. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few differing answers to this question on stack overflow. This is the correct one. It addresses the issue of why have multiple infowindows open in the first place.