# Google Map V3 infowindows

Tags: javascript

I’m developing a website that incorporates a Google map v3 and I would like to know how to programmatically close the infowindows that can be opened when the user clicks on the icons that are loaded with the map.  I don’t mean the infowindows opened when the markers the site places on the map are clicked on.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223574/google-maps-auto-close-open-infowindows?rq=1

Comment: @user2078143 are you looking for closing the infoWindows?

Comment: Hi, yes. The infowindows that can be opened when the  icons that are automatically load with the map are clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    icon: image
                });


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'some text'
                });

marker.addListener('mousedown', function() {
                    infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                    if (!marker.open) {
                        infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        marker.open = true;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            infowindow.close();
                            marker.open = false;
                        }, 2000);

                    } else {
                        infowindow.close();
                        marker.open = false;
                    }
                });
```

In ur case u just have to replace marker with icon , icon or whatever must have a mousedown or click listener.

And marker.open & close is just a variable